# Rails Single-Sign on service and communicate to a REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

At my company we are developing several web applications that uses a REST API server.

**First a little introduction.**

The app provides the ability to manage users through the REST API and allows the users to login to the app.

Right now the REST API is for internal use only because we plan to develop more apps and communicate to the REST API as the central point of data access. We are handling the REST API authentication with a "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant" implementation for the internal apps.

What we need is a Single-Sign on service for all the apps, we want a user to login to an app and if he/she access to another of our apps he/she will be already loged in.

We have been experimenting with the CAS protocol, with the CASino library specifically and it works great.

The problem is we don't know how to handle the flow between the apps, the REST API and the SSO service, also I don't know if there is a better choice regarding SSO services.

**My questions are...**

1. How we could handle the flow between the apps, the REST API and the
   SSO service, because the REST API should be stateless it should not
   communicate to the SSO service? or is there a way to communicate the
   REST API to the SSO service?
2. Is there a better choice to implement a Single-Sign on service,
       maybe OAth or OpenID and are this options suitable for REST APIs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. Your REST API will have to talk to the SSO server to validate the Access Token, unless all the information it needs is encrypted inside the Access Token. Not sure what you mean by "flow between the apps", you should have all apps talking to a central SSO server.

When a user wants to create an account on WebApp1, the account should be created on the SSO server, either by redirecting them there or if you need a differently styled signup form for each web app, then via an AJAX call to the SSO server's REST API. I would recommend the latter as redirecting is more difficult to debug and it can make a bad user experience.

Make sure the messaging is clear, i.e. not "Sign up for a WebApp1 account", but "Sign up for a MyCompany account to get access to WebApp1".

2. OAuth 2.0 is very popular and people have more experience with it, so it's easier to get help or integrate with apps created by others.

The [doorkeeper gem](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) is a good server library.

OAuth 2.0 is normally used when the SSO server doesn't trust the client apps (e.g. Facebook, Twitter), but it can be implemented in such a way to skip the client authorization step (where the user is asked to approve the client app), and you can use the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) via a REST API.

CAS is easier than OAuth. It is fairly easy to implement the basic endpoints and that way you can customize it as you wish.

I worked on a CAS-based server with a custom implementation (not sure if it was even really CAS-compliant). The authentication was done with Devise (I don't recommend Devise if you're going to customise it a lot, make your own in this case). The original flow was that the user went to the website, clicked Login/Register and then was redirected to the SSO server and after the user logged in, redirected back with a one-time ticket that the website's backend exchanged to an access token via a REST API call.

Then we added a REST API that was called from each website with AJAX. You send the username/password/captcha/etc and get back an auth token, which the site sends to its own backend. The SSO REST API can also set a cookie on its own domain, so that if the user visit another of our web apps it makes a call on pageload to check if the user is logged in. This way you're automatically logged in on every webapp without the redirect mess.

All tokens issued + the associated user info were sent to a fast Node.js app that would save them to Redis, and the app backends would call this app to validate the access tokens really fast, without putting load to the SSO Rails app.